# WPF and MVVM: Changing data binding converter at runtime

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, ivalueconverter

I am using WPF and the MVVM pattern in my user interface. In my ViewModel I have a List containing distances in millimetres, which I display in a ListView by binding ListView.ItemsSource to the List. However, I would like the values displayed to use a more natural unit - either metres or feet depending on the state of a "metric" checkbox.

I have written a couple of simple classes, MillimetresToMetresConverter and MillimetresToFeetConverter, both of which implement IValueConverter. Although I can set the Converter property on my data binding to one or the other, I am unsure how to change between these converters when the state of the checkbox changes.

My plan was to have a field "IValueConverter lengthConverter" on my ViewModel which I could set to one converter or the other, then in my XAML do `...="{Binding Converter={Binding Path=lengthConverter}}"` - unfortunately this does not work since Converter is not a dependency property.

How can change the converter used by the data binding at runtime?

Comment: You should be able to use DependencyObject.GetBinding(DependencyProperty), e.g. myTextBlock.GetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty) to get (and modify) the Binding object.

Comment: Unfortunately, following the MVVM pattern means that code would need to live in the ViewModel - which has no reference to the view and thus cannot touch "myTextBlock".

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time when using the MVVM methodology, you can do the formatting task in the VM classes. In your case, you could add a Format property to the VM class, and based on the value of the Format property, return a well formated string.

See [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/3fe270cd107f184f) for more information.

Comment: Exactly. Converters are very rare in an MVVM application, normally only popping up in custom controls.

Comment: Let's assume my ViewModel has a `List<int> Distances` property which I am binding my ListView.ItemsSource to. Are you suggesting that instead of Distances.get returning the list as-is, it should return a different list - with the conversion already applied?

Comment: @Paul: yep.  A ViewModel is just a bit ValueConverter ;-).  You can read a similar discussion on the WPF Disciples discussion board: http://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/msg/c29b3935ec9d3c4e

Comment: Maybe I oversimplified when asking the question. Let's assume that instead of List<int>, I have List<LargeDataStructure> and I want to apply a conversion to a single member of LargeDataStructure. It seems to be quite heavy-handed to create and expose List<NewLargeDataStructure>, where a NewLargeDataStructure references a LargeDataStructure (or worse, makes a copy of it) and re-exposes all but one of its properties in the same way. A ValueConverter seems much lighter - just changing the single property "on the fly".

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest a simple alternative solution: Create a small `FormatMillimetresConverter` in your ViewModel, whose `UseMetric` property is bound to the "metric" checkbox.

Comment: Thanks - but once I've got a FormatMillimetresConverter in the ViewModel, how do I get the ListView to use it?

Comment: Good point. :-) You could export one instance of it as a static property of your ViewModel and then access it via "... Converter={x:Static local:ViewModel.MyFormatMillimetresConverter}", but somehow that's not very elegant...

Comment: What about creating the FormatMillimetresConverter in <Window.Resources>? Then it's available as a static resource and you can attach it as a converter to the ListView.ItemsSource with "... Converter={StaticResource..." and to the checkbox with "{Binding Source={StaticResource...".